# pytorch: log_softmax base 2?

Tags: pytorch

I want to get surprisal values from logit outputs from PyTorch, using log base 2.

One way to do this, given a logits tensor, is:

```
probs = nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim = 2)
surprisals = -torch.log2(probs)
```

However, PyTorch provides a function that combines log and softmax, which is faster than the above:

```
surprisals = -nn.functional.log_softmax(logits, dim = 2)
```

But this seems to return values in base e, which I don't want. Is there a function like `log_softmax`, but which uses base 2? I have tried `log2_softmax` and `log_softmax2`, neither of which seems to work, and haven't had any luck finding documentation online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using the fact that logarithm bases can be easily altered by the following mathematical identity

[image]

[image] is what `F.log_softmax()` is giving you. All you need to do is

```
surprisals = - (1 / torch.log(2.)) * nn.functional.log_softmax(logits, dim = 2)
```

Its just a scalar multiplication. So, it hardly has any performance penalty.